# How to convert .png stripes to one .gif file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

How to convert .png stripes to one .gif file in photoshop or any other application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to animate the stripes? Can you post an example?

Comment: Do you want to take a png SPRITE and make it animated as a gif? :)

Comment: Hello thsi question is unclear about what it is you want as an answer. Could you please edit your post to be more clear.

Comment: Obviously the user has said that he cannot edit his question. Asking him to "please clarify" therefore make no sense... get real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can convert a series of PNG images (or any other still images format) into a GIF file.

The first way would be to do it online using an online tool such as [this one](http://gifmaker.me), [this one](http://makeagif.com) or [this one](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-gif).

Doing it with software is also possible. On a Mac, [GIFfun](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8869/giffun), [Gif Brewery](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8869/giffun), [Pic Gif](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/picgif/id784260229?mt=12) or [Gif Grabber](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/gifgrabber/id668208984?mt=12) can help you.

In your question, you mention using Photoshop. Using the Adobe suite is also possible; in this case you could drag and drop the images into Premiere Pro and export as a video file, then open the file into Photoshop and save for web as a GIF. Or drag them onto the Photoshop timeline, and export as a GIF.

I would recommend, whatever process you end up choosing, that your images aren't too large, and all have the same height and width.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)  
I can't edit my question, so here it is again:  
Is there any way that I can convert a series of PNG images into a animated GIF file?

Comment: Didn't my answer help you? I think I was quite specific but if there is a part of my answer that you don't understand please be more specific.